# Nifi ExecuteSQLRecord: how to capture performance bottleneck

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi

### Objective

I have [Apache Nifi Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi) container on Azure VM with attached premium very high-throughput SSD disk. I have MSSQL Server 2012 database on AWS. Nifi to database communication happens through mssql jar v6.2, and through high-throughtput AWS Direct Connect MPLS network.

Within Nifi Flow only one processor is executed - `ExecuteSQLRecord`. It use only one thread/CPU and has 4 GB JVM Heap Space available. `ExecuteSQLRecord` execute query that return 1 million of rows, which equals to 60MB Flow File. Query is based on table indexes, so there is nothing to optimize on DB side. Query looks like: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN x AND y`.

### The issue

`ExecuteSQLRecord` with 1 thread/CPU, 1 query , retrieves 1M of rows (60MB) in 40 seconds.
In the same time, the same query run from MSSMS and database internal network takes 18 seconds.

In the same time query is already optimized on DB side (with indexes), and throughtput scale linearly with increasing number of threads/CPUs - network is not a bottleneck.

### Questions

1. Is this performance okay for Nifi 1 CPU? Is it okay that Nifi spends 22 seconds (from 40) for retrieval and storing the results to Content Repository?
2. How does Nifi pull the data from MSSQL Server? Is this a pull approach? If yes, maybe we have to many roundtrips?
3. How can I check how much time Nifi spending on converting result set to CSV, and how much time for writting into Content Repository?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the latest Docker image (1.11.4)? If so you should be able to set the fetch size on the ExecuteSQLRecord processor (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6865)

I got a couple of different results when I searched for the default fetch size for the MSSQL driver, one site said 1 and another said 32. In your case for that many records I'd imagine you'd want it to be way higher (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/legacy/aa342344(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#use-the-appropriate-fetch-size for setting the appropriate fetch size).

Comment: thank you for your answer! I used 1.10.0, bit I've just switched to 1.11.4 and tested the solution. I played with different `fetchSize`s: from 1k to 1m. I was able to win only one second. So number of roundtrips isn't a bottleneck or that property is ignored by Nifi or MS SQL.

Comment: after all options I tried, I'm inclined to think that ~100MB/min is an optimal speed for  1 CPU/2 GB RAM, and further performance should be gained by scaling number of CPUs. Am I close to truth?

Answer (score 1):

To add to Matt's answer, you can examine the [provenance data](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#data_provenance) for each flowfile and see the lineage duration (amount of time) it spent in each segment of the flow. You can also see the [status history](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Status_History) for every processor, so you can examine the data in/out by size and number of flowfiles, CPU usage, etc. for each processor.

Comment: yes, thanks for the suggestion. I do know about provenance and status history. The trick with ExecuteSQLRecord processor is that it statistic contains all at once: from starting querying the database till end of persistance to Content Repository. So the bottleneck may be in database, network, RAM, disk, maybe something else. And you're   Nifi doesn't tell you where exactly) You need to play with different options or maybe to implement a custom processor (which is too long for me)

Comment: If you need to get more granular, attaching a Java profiler is probably the next step.

Comment: thank you! Currently I have to stop my investigations because of deadlines, but this is a good point